# How does lambda deal with unbound variables inside its body in scheme?

Tags: lambda, scope, scheme, racket, r5rs

In this code snippet:

```
(begin
  (define f '())
  ((lambda ()
     (set! f (lambda (x) (g x 5)))))
  (define (g x y) (+ x y))
  (f 5))
```

when `(set! f (lambda...))` is evaluated, the variable g is not bound to any location.
As the spec for R5RS (link [here](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/)) says:

> The environment in effect when the lambda expression was evaluated is
>   remembered as part of the procedure. When the procedure is later
>   called with some actual arguments, the environment in which the lambda
>   expression was evaluated will be extended by binding the variables in
>   the formal argument list to fresh locations, the corresponding actual
>   argument values will be stored in those locations, and the expressions
>   in the body of the lambda expression will be evaluated sequentially in
>   the extended environment.

where "the environment in effect" at one point is defined as:

> An identifier that names a location is called a variable and is said
>   to be bound to that location. The set of all visible bindings in
>   effect at some point in a program is known as the environment in
>   effect at that point.

so the inner lambda should only capture an environment like `{f: (location #1)}`; and when it is evaluated by calling `(f 5)` the environment used to evaluate its body should be `{f: (location #1), x: (location #2)}` which does not contain `g`.

but DrRacket (and also petite, which is a R6RS implementation) gives 10 on evaluating the above snippet. so the environment does contain `g`. why?

=====

It seems that scheme requires define statements to appear only at the beginning of `<body>`. But this code snippet returns 10 as well:

```
(begin
  (define (f x) (g x 5))
  (define (g x y) (+ x y))
  (f 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out the reason.

R5RS says:

```
A <body> containing internal definitions can always be converted into
a completely equivalent letrec expression
```

where letrec is described as:

```
The <variable>s are bound to fresh locations holding undefined values,
the <init>s are evaluated in the resulting environment (in some
unspecified order), each <variable> is assigned to the result of the
corresponding <init>, the <body> is evaluated in the resulting
environment
```

and for top-level definitions:

> Some implementations of Scheme use an initial environment in which all
>   possible variables are bound to locations, most of which contain
>   undefined values. Top level definitions in such an implementation are
>   truly equivalent to assignments.

So that behavior is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

So, the R5RS therefore means that

```
(begin
   (define f '())
   ((lambda () (set! f (lambda (x) (g x 5))) ) )
   (define (g x y) (+ x y))
   (f 5) )
```

means the same thing as

```
(letrec
    ((f '())
     (g +)
     (x x)
     (y y) )
 (f 5) )
```

or, more simply

```
(let*
    ((g +)
     (f (lambda (x) (g x 5)) ) )
  (f 5) )
```

In my (limited) experience, it has always been much clearer to program with the the "let" binding forms (**let**, **let***, **letrec**) in the first place, and avoid **set!** as much as possible.  When I do that, I find my programs are much easier to understand, especially when I come back to look at them months later!